# Strange behaviour while setting border with corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

I want to set the round border for UIButton to 1px (as thick as the table separator), so I set it by 1/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale.

In my Custom UIButton class:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2;
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
```

Result in iphone 6plus which is expected:

[image: Iphone 6 plus result]

Result in other iOS devices:

[image: Other results]

I've tried the anti-alias and rasterized options. However, it got the same result.

It would work well if I set the borderWidth > 2pt.